# Getting an error while trying to connect to Sybase in node.js

Tags: node.js, sybase

By using the npm package for sybase (npm install sybase), I'm trying to connect to sybase.

I am getting an error message

> Unable to access jarfile ./JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar

I know there is an issue in accessing the JAR file and these are the two lines in my sybaseDB.js file

```
var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE1 = process.env.PWD + "/node_modules/sybase/JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar";

var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE2 = "./JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar";
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I faced same problem like you and I just solved.

All you need to do is type all the way down path directories from root (AIX, UNIX => "/") or Windows "C:" to JavaSybaseLink.jar. Ok, that's not a very fancy/smart solution but it works for me.

All you need to do is:

**UNIX, AIX Based solution:**

```
var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE="/home/someUser/MyReactNodeJSProject/node_modules/sybase/JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar";
```

**Windows Based solution:**

```
var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE = "C:\\MyWorkFolder\\MyReactNodeJSProject\\node_modules\\sybase\\JavaSybaseLink\\dist\\JavaSybaseLink.jar";
```

**Note:** Don't forget that in Windows you need to put double slash.
Obviusly, the process running user must have the rights to access to entire path of PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE and the jar file itself.

And pass var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE to Sybase constructor function, don't forget constructor Sybase definition needs LogTiming value to set so you need to create and set (no problem)

```
var Sybase = require('sybase'),
    logTiming = true,
    javaJarPath = "C:\\MyWorkFolder\\MyReactNodeJSProject\\node_modules\\sybase\\JavaSybaseLink\\dist\\JavaSybaseLink.jar", 
    db = new Sybase('172.172.172.15', 9999, 'MyDB', 'pass', logTiming, javaJarPath);
    
    ....
    ....
    Your connection code and so on ....
    ....
    ....
```

This works for me.

Comment: Hi cometinSatela, welcome to Stackoverflow. An OS agnostic solution would be a better approach here. e.g. using `path.resolve` and `path.sep`